# Overwriting local files with remote files causes Unity Standalone Application To Freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a developer using the Unity Game Engine trying to overwrite local files with files from an FTP Server. I am using the System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes function to do so.

When I start the application and I trigger the code that has been updated, my application will freeze.

In my Windows Form, the code arrives here, it uses the WebClient instance to download the file, and overwrites it if it is larger than the local file:

```
public void downloadFile (WebClient webClient, string urlAddress, 
    string location, byte[] localFile)
{
        webClient.Proxy = null;
        webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<user>", "<pass>");
        byte[] fileData = webClient.DownloadData("ftp://"+ urlAddress);
        /*
         * Only download if bytes of remote file 
         * is larger than bytes of local file
         */
        if (fileData.Length > localFile.Length)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(location, fileData);
        }
}
```

Using FileStream causes the application to freeze just as well.

```
FileStream _FileStream = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
_FileStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
_FileStream.Close();
```

And I also tried writing all the files that needed updating to a Temporary folder, and then using File.Copy

What am I suppose to be doing to properly overwrite files?

Comment: Sounds like the files are open, but to keep unity from freezing you should async write, If you are trying to do a updater you should do a application that will check for updates, if any download then launch your unity game. My example here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=993iGWhVa3c checks MD5 hashes for changes of files